При нажатии Host+F10 в терминале Ubuntu из под VirtualBox экран становится чёрным
Я работаю в Windows 10. Установил VirtualBox 7.0. Установил в нём Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. В Ubuntu открыл терминал и в терминале открыл MidnightCommander (mc). Обычно по клавише F10 mc закрывается. Но из под виртуальной машины реакции нет никакой. Тогда я нажимаю Host+F10 (Host - правый Ctrl). При этом экран Ubuntu становится чёрным и моргает курсор в левом верхнем углу. При этом на нажатие каких либо клавиш не реагирует. Вернуть обратно экран Ubuntu не получается. Приходится перезапускать Ubuntu, чтоб продолжить в ней работать.
Не имею понятия, чей это косяк - VirtualBox или Ubuntu,
Как убрать этот странный эффект и сделать возможным использование функциональных клавиш в терминале?
UPD:
Нашёл, как активировать использование клавиши F10. Для этого необходимо в терминале Ubuntu войти в меню Preferences и снять галочку с Enable the menu accelerator key (F10 by default). Остался вопрос, куда улетает Ubuntu по сочетанию клавиш Host+F10

Нашёл ответ на Хабр Q&A.
Чтоб активировать кнопку F10 на использования её в терминале, нужно зайти в меню терминала Preferences и снять галочку с Enable the menu accelerator key (F10 by default).
Host-клавиша эмулирует нажатие сочетания CTRL+ALT в Ubuntu. Нажатием Host+F10 я переключаюсь в TTY 10, на котором у меня ничего не запущено. Вернуться в графическое окружение можно по сочетанию Host+F1, Host+F2 или Host+F6, в зависимости от настроек. У меня это было Host+F2.
